# Extracting numbers from a list in a cell in Excel

Tags: excel

Could anyone tell me how to extract a list of numbers from a field in an MS Excel Spreadsheet in to separate cells please? The numbers are delimited by commas.  EG 506, 507, 508, 509

Thanks

Comment: Data > Text to Columns

Comment: Search google for `Text to Column in excel`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Solution I needed is below though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999)),"")
```

and copy across.

[image]

Comment: Great. That is just what I needed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the number cells, and click **Data > Text to Columns**.
2. In the **Step 1** of the **Convert Text to Columns Wizard**, check **Delimited**.
3. Click Next to go to **step 2** of the Wizard, and select the **"Comma"** symbol.
4. Click Next and choose **"General"** type.
5. Click **Finish**, and then the selected numbers are split into columns.

Ready!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Solution I needed is below though!